# Convert seconds interval data to hourly mean representation in LESS TIME

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data file containing readings sampled at 30 seconds duration. File organization is:

```
> head(dframe)
            timestamp    power
1 2015-08-01 00:00:04 584.1379
2 2015-08-01 00:00:34 585.8087
3 2015-08-01 00:01:04 584.9335
4 2015-08-01 00:01:34 584.4366
5 2015-08-01 00:02:04 584.2829
```

Now to represent the 30 second duration data into hourly mean I use following `R` command:

```
df = aggregate(list(power=dframe$power),by=list(timestamp=cut(as.POSIXct(dframe$timestamp),"hour")),mean)
```

This works perfectly. But, the actual issue is with time it takes for large files (data of one year). Can I somehow reduce the time it takes for conversion process? In other words, is there any other best alternative which takes less time for conversion of seconds data to hourly mean data in R?

**UPDATE**:
 I used 4 different methods for the same problem as suggested by @akrun and @Joshua. For other users of stack overflow here I am providing the usage of all methods and the respective time taken

```
dframe<-read.csv(path,head=TRUE,sep=",")
dframe$timestamp<- as.POSIXct(dframe$timestamp)
xframe = dframe
#using aggregate
system.time(
df1<- aggregate(list(power=dframe$power),by=list(timestamp=cut(dframe$timestamp,"hour")),mean)
)
# using data.table
system.time(
dfx<-setDT(dframe)[, list(power= mean(power)) ,(timestamp= cut(timestamp, 'hour'))]
)
# using dplyr
system.time( 
xframe %>% group_by(timestamp= cut(timestamp, 'hour')) %>% summarise(power=mean(power))
)
#using xts
system.time({
  x <- xts(dframe$power,dframe$timestamp)
  h <- period.apply(x, endpoints(x, "hours"), mean)
  h <- data.frame(timestamp=trunc(index(h),'hours'), power=coredata(h))
})
```

Respective times taken on two (one month, three month) different datasets are: For one month data set:

```
Method       user  system elapsed 
Aggregate    0.137   0.005   0.142
data.table   0.031   0.001   0.032 
dplyr        0.035   0.001   0.036  
xts          0.053   0.000   0.053
```

For three month data set:

```
Aggregate    0.456   0.019   0.475 
data.table   0.099   0.002   0.102  
dplyr        0.099   0.004   0.103  
xts          0.158   0.004   0.161
```

**Caveat**: All approaches except *xts* changes the type of timestamp from `POSIXct` to `Factor`. This means you have to convert again type of timestamp column, that will incur some more cpu cycles. In short, If in the end you further need POSIXct timestamp then xts is the best, otherwise go for data.table.

**DATASET** Dataset used can be found at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nncgpt1pog6tseo/chiller2.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Can you try with `dplyr`, `library(dplyr); dframe %>% group_by(timestamp= cut(as.POSIXct(timestamp), 'hour') %>% summarise(power=mean(power))`

Comment: I'm guessing `cut` is causing a lot of the slow-down

Comment: @akrun. Thanks. data.table is taking lesser time than all the options I have used. Please provide your first (using data.table) comment as an answer. In the meantime I will add the statistics in the main question. I am still confused why did it gave bad results in the morning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `aggregate` is slow.  We can use `data.table` for making this fast.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dframe)`), we use `cut` to create a grouping variable from 'timestamp' and get the `mean` of 'power'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dframe)[, list(power= mean(power)) ,(timestamp= cut(as.POSIXct(timestamp), 'hour'))]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this aggregation in less than half the time using tools from the xts package.

```
# sample data
set.seed(21)
N <- 2e6
dframe <- data.frame(timestamp=seq(Sys.time(), by="30 sec", length.out=N),
                     power=rnorm(N))
# aggregate
system.time(a <- aggregate(list(power=dframe$power),by=list(timestamp=cut(dframe$timestamp,"hour")), mean))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.456   0.000   2.457 

# xts
system.time({
  x <- xts(dframe$power, dframe$timestamp)
  h <- period.apply(x, endpoints(x, "hours"), mean)
  h <- data.frame(timestamp=trunc(index(h),'hours'), power=coredata(h))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.888   0.004   0.893
```

Comment: I used xts and compared it other methods. Its output is not impressive. It seems data.table is taking very less time. I have provided all the results as an update in main question

Comment: Xts behaves in a strange manner. Whenever I use xts packages it results in 721 observations while as rest of three methods mentioned in question result in 720 observations. Also the hourly means provided by xts are slightly different than the rest of methods. For clarification, I have included dataset in question also.

Comment: @HaroonRashid: that is likely a timezone issue. You should be able to resolve it by setting the timezone on the `POSIXct` column (e.g. `attr(dframe$timestamp, 'tzone') <- "UTC"`.

Comment: I used `attr(dframe$timestamp, "tzone") <- "Asia/Kolkata"`, but still no effect. My timestamp column is correctly set, because the output of `head(dframe$timestamp[1])  is "2015-08-01 00:00:04 IST"`. Which is true.

Comment: I suspect the period.apply function. I found one interesting thing with xts(). Whenever, I use xts to convert my data the output timestamp column is always in POSIXct form whileas in remaining methods it gets converted to factor form.

Comment: @HaroonRashid: I doubt it's `period.apply` because it's just a simple wrapper around `sapply`. It might be `endpoints`, but it could also be something odd in `cut.POSIXt` (i.e. not an xts issue).

Comment: But all the remaining three approaches produce similar result, only xts produces different results. This is the only reason I suspect xts to be doing something wrong.

Comment: @HaroonRashid: The other 3 approaches all use `cut.POSIXt`, not 3 independent approaches. If something is odd with `cut.POSIXt`, then all 3 other approaches will produce the same odd result. In short, you need to look at both results and determine which is most reasonable.